# FileSystem::unlink() FAILED in PHING build-file

Tags: git, phing

I've cloned a git repo in a new build folder with phing. Now I try to delete the .git-folder from my cloned repo with

```
<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${builddir}" failonerror="true"/>
</target>
```

But when I do that the task fail with this error message. I'm using Win 7 with xampp 1.8.3

```
build.xml:39:26: Unable to delete file C:\xampp\htdocs\build\xxx\.git\objects\00\0ffcba3ef0570b9ca0a89214e25c8e762427ff: FileSystem::unlink() FAILED. Cannot unlink 'C:\xampp\htdocs\build\xxx\.git\objects\00\0ffcba3ef0570b9ca0a89214e25c8e762427ff'.
```

Has anybody an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: @orciny Please stop unnecessarily adding the PHP tag to phing questions.

Comment: Why not? They are PHP questions as Phing and all of it's tasks are written in PHP. Phing questions tend to get missed due to lack of a prominent tag.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to change file permissions inside .git subdirectories
By default files `.git/objects/pack` have read-only permissions (`ls -l` from cygwin showing `-r--r--r--` permissions for *.idx and *.pack files)

Next piece of code worked for me

```
<target name="clean">
    <chmod mode="0777">
        <fileset dir="${targetdir}" defaultexcludes="false">
            <include name="**/.git/**" />
        </fileset>
    </chmod>
    <delete includeemptydirs="true">
        <fileset dir="${targetdir}" defaultexcludes="false">
            <include name="**/*" />
        </fileset>
    </delete>
</target>
```